# What would be the appropriate word for this project title: "optimal", "optimum", or "ideal"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm looking to create an appropriate title for a science fair project and I'm questioning which of these three words would be most grammatically appropriate and correct: "optimal","optimum" or "ideal". "Creating the Optimal Computer for Literacy at Half the Cost", "Creating the Optimum Computer for Literacy at Half the Cost", or "Creating the Ideal Computer for Literacy at Half the Cost"? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: all three are fine.

As for the first two options, let's see what *Merriam Webster* has to say:

> *Optimal* and *optimum* both mean “best possible” or “most favorable.” *Optimal* is used solely as an adjective, as in “optimal method of completion, while *optimum* functions as both a noun, as in something “being at its optimum,” and an adjective, “optimum method,” although this is less common.
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/optimum-vs-optimal

As this article explains, English writers borrowed the noun *optimum* from Latin in the 19th century. Within a short time, *optimum* began to be used as an adjective and almost simultaneously a new word, *optimal*, appeared, which was also used as an adjectival form of *optimum*. Today, both words are used as adjectives, but *optimal* appears to be used somewhat more frequently.

As for *ideal*, in this case, its meaning is virtually identical to *optimal/optimum*.

> **ideal**
>
> Adjective
>
> 1 Satisfying one's conception of what is perfect; most suitable.
>
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ideal

Answer (score 0):

I've seen optimal/optimum applied more frequently to cases where the results can be objectively measured, for example "An algorithm optimized for speed."

Ideal is the better choice if the criteria is less objective and more open to human opinion, belief, or even personal preference.  For example, "The ideal candidate for Governor."

Though I don't really know what you mean by "Computer for Literacy", I'd suspect you want 'ideal' or one of its close synonyms like 'preferable' or 'most suitable'/'best suited'.